# how to send a notification from django to twisted?

Tags: python, django, twisted, signals, django-signals

My application consists of a [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) "backend server" and a [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) "middleware". The twisted part is a [collection of services](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html#auto8) set up in a [.tac file](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html#auto5) to access the database, provide contents via www or xml. The django part handles all interaction with the user on the website.

The twisted web service instantiates the django WSGI application in what I think is the [canonical way](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html#auto20):

```
# .../wsgi/app.py:
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()

# .../web_service.py:
# (twisted imports...)
from wsgi.app import application
class WebServer(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        Resource.__init__(self)
        self.wsgi_resource = WSGIResource(reactor,
                                          reactor.getThreadPool(),
                                          application)
```

Now I need to send a notification that for example the user has logged in from the django part to the twisted part, ideally to one of the services. I am trying to to use a [django signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) for the purpose. Sending the signal works, but I don't really see how to obtain a reference to a twisted object to serve as target for the signal:

- The services are all instantiated in `app.tac` and it does not seem possible to import these objects from that file or re-obtain a reference to them once the twisted app is running.
- On the `#twisted` IRC channel, I got the advice to pass a reference to the service that is supposed to be the target for my signal to the django app when I instantiate that, but as the code snippet above shows, the django app is simply a `WSGIHandler` object and even if I manage to inject the service reference in there somehow, I don't see how to access it from within the app. Also, that approach would couple backend and middleware rather tightly - which is what a signal intends to prevent in the first place.

**How can I send a notification from Django to Twisted ?**

Answer (score 2):

The Django-ized solution is probably to put an object into `settings.py`.  This is, of course, terrible.  However, since Django consistently relies on this piece of global state, to the point where it doesn't even have any other widely known or used mechanisms for providing state to your application, you may just have to live with it.

You can add something like this to your tac file:

```
import settings
settings.twisted_listener = your_service
```

This is not a recommendation so much as a "there's probably no cleaner ways than this"-ation.  In a better world than this one, Django would not have `settings.py`.  It would have APIs that accept arguments for configuring applications.